# What is the number of reducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ of the form $x^2+ax+b$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> What is the number of reducible polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}_p$  of the form $x^2+ax+b$?

My attempt:

If the polynomial is reducible, then it can be factored as $(x-c)(x-d)$. We have $p$ choices for $c$ and $p$ choices for $d$, so the number is $p^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Those polynomials can have two forms: either $(x-h)(x-k)$ with $h\ne k$ or $(x-h)^2$.

The latter are $p$; the former are $\dbinom{p}{2}=\dfrac{p(p-1)}{2}$, because you can't distinguish the order of the roots.

Comment: so the number is p(p+1)/2. thanks

Comment: the number of irreducible polynomials of the form $x^2+ax+b$ is = the number of total polynomials fthe form- the number f reducible ones=$p^2-p(p+1)/2=p(p-1)/2$

Comment: @jaggu The degree $2$ monic polynomials are $p^2$ (you can choose $a$ and $b$ arbitrarily), so…